# How do I properly animate a cloak

Tags: animation, rigging, cloth-simulation

You see I'm having trouble figuring out how to animate this. I've already tried to use the cloth physics but that went horribly and I'm pretty sure that's my fault, but oh well.

[image: here it is]

Comment: This is my first attempt at anything like this and I can't watch videos tutorials, because of my lack of bandwidth

Comment: you should try to give your cloak a Mesh Deform modifier and rig the Object of the Mesh Deform with bones

Comment: trying it out now its not exactly working :/ , but I'll keep trying thanks

Comment: nope not working, but if I ever need to to make a hedgehog now I know how lol thanks for your suggestion though

Comment: you could also create several vertical chains of bones all around the cloak

Comment: Is there a less painful way? I'm not lazy I swear

Comment: you don't need a lot, like 3 chains of 3 bones around the cloak could be enough